# How to disassemble this Technic combination?

Tags: technic, disassembly

How should I disassemble the axle (7) attached in this model?

(I tried using a brick separator but failed to remove it.)

[image: Excerpt from manual]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the longest technic shaft you have, and use it to push the #7 shaft out just enough to where you can finish pulling it out with your fingers. Then pull out the long shaft.

Comment: I'd suggest using not the longest axle; but an axle 8 with stop - easier to remove afterwards. Also, the yellow beam looks like it should be easy to remove beforehand.